# CloudFormation: Waiter StackCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, sam

I had issues trying to deploy a cloudformation change through the `sam deploy` command and therefore decided that deleting the stack and recreating it might be the best option. I was however unable to delete the stack since it seems several resources were created manually. I therefore deleted the stack by setting those resources as optional.

When I try to deploy the stack again, I am getting `Waiter StackCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state` error. How can I find more information on what the underlying issue is?

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DescribeStacks operation: Stack with id <Stack> does not exist
<Stack> will be created.
Creating ChangeSet ChangeSet-2023-01-14T01-30-51Z
Deploying stack <Stack>. Follow in console: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-west-2
ChangeSet ChangeSet-2023-01-14T01-30-51Z in <Stack> succeeded
            "StackStatus": "REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS",
<Stack> reached REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS
Deploying stack <Stack>. Follow in console: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-west-2
Waiting for stack-create-complete

Waiter StackCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Stacks[].StackStatus" we matched expected path: "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" at least once

Command failed.
Please see the logs above.
```

Comment: Can you add your template resulting in the error?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you trying to run the same template on existing resources.
You should delete manually first the resources and then deploy again.